# How can I display chosen array contents to the user in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a random number generator and I also have an array of 30 items, however I require it to use the numbers generated to get the positions of the items in the array and display it. Sorry if I don't make much sense, I'm still trying to understand it myself!

Here's my random number generator code!

public void passRndNum() throws IOException

```
    ArrayList <Integer> aNumber = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    {
        aNumber.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(aNumber);
    for (int i = 0;i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        aPlayer[i].receiveCard(aNumber.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number?

Comment: I can create a random number however I can't understand how to assign the number to the position of the item in the array to display it to the user.

Comment: Do you understand arrays at all? Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: The displayed code doesn't use an *array* and doesn't create a random number between 0 and 29. Is your initial question off, or is the code wrong?

Comment: My original question is a bit off yeah, I have an array which reads in a file which contains card details, I need to be able to use that with the random number generator to get the card details to the user

Comment: you generate random number. how many times do you want?

Comment: I would need 15 random numbers to be displayed, sorry about the post being so confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create random number between 0 and 29

Yes.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.nextInt(30);
```

> to represent a counter

Yes.

```
int counter = rnd.nextInt(30);
```

> of an array of 30 items

Yes, you can have an array of 30 items. Lets call it ... `myArray`.

> and then call that counter and item to the display?

Yes.

```
System.out.println(counter + ": " + myArray[counter]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Sorry about the question not being very straightforward!